# Error related to global.asax when combine MVC inside compiled asp net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-asax, merge-conflict-resolution

I am trying to combine ASP .NET MVC into other Web Site (having compiled ASP .NET Web Form application) 
the first one (ASP .NET MVC) has Global.asax but the second one doesn't have physically Global.asax file

now when I open any page in the web site the following message are appeared :

```
CS0433: The type 'ASP.global_asax' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\hers\69bee5e9\5fef09ef\assembly\dl3\bac6f816\6e0b73aa_a081cf01\HEDNet_deploy.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\hers\69bee5e9\5fef09ef\App_global.asax.tsvmjkw7.dll
```

so it is look the `Global.asax` of the asp MVC conflicts with exist web application (asp net web form) however their is no file called global.asax for the second one nor `App_global.asax.dll` at the bin folder .
Please Note also : we don't have the source code of the second application (ASP .NET web Form)
so I am trying to avoid using Global ASAX in ASP net MVC however so I need to handle `Application_Start` event outside of Global as a solution to solve the conflict , so how can I handle the `Application_Start` event outside avoid using `GLOBAL.asax` ? or if you have any solution to solve the conflict will be more appreciated 
thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is ok to use global.asax withing mvc but if you do won't for any reason you can still create a http module: http://erraticdev.blogspot.sk/2010/08/writing-ihttpmodule-thats-able-to.html

Comment: Thanks , I have used HTTMLModule, your article reference was very helpful.